Flask App not deploying through Azure DevOps
I am currently deploying a Python flask application to an Azure WebApp and when I manually deploy it through VSCode it works but when I deploy it through Azure DevOps it doesn't work. I have created a release pipeline that runs the requirements.txt file and also archives the file and then a release pipeline that deploys the application to the webapp.
When I look at the kudu in the webapp then I see that the files are deployed but the application is not running. My guess is that when I deploy it through VSCode it creates an antenv and also deploys the package as a zip file and not as individual files but when I deploy through Azure DevOps it deploys all the files individually. I have attached photos of my pipeline below.



If app is not running after deploying, you may check on webapp side. see if any option there.

To test the issue, I created a simple Python flask application and deployed it to the Azure Web App. It works without problem. The following is my code and steps.

My Code in my_flask_app folder: 

app.py:
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

requirements.txt:
blinker==1.8.2
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==3.0.3
itsdangerous==2.2.0
Jinja2==3.1.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
Werkzeug==3.0.4

startup.txt: (The startup.txt file is used to specify the command that should be run to start the Flask application when it is deployed to Azure.)
"gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app:app" 


Pipeline configurations:

Build pipeline YAML:
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.x'
    addToPath: true

- script: |
    cd "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/my_flask_app"
    python -m venv antenv
    source antenv/bin/activate
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/my_flask_app'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- publish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

Release pipeline:


Test result:



Please ensure that the startup command for your Flask application is correctly set.
